# JSF - graphicImage - replace broken image

Tags: jsf, graphicimage

I am wondering, is there a way to replace broken image with some other one in JSF when using grapicImage?

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images) in JavaScript:

```
<img src="image.png" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/images/noimage.gif';" />
```

However graphicImage doesn't support onError handling.

Comment: Do you have jQuery at hands?

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the tip! I looked into it and found a simple solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It possible using a simple jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var $ = jQuery;
      var Element = ".poster";
      $(Element).error(function () {
          $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "error.jpeg");
      });
      });
</script>
```